# Prestashop.. Customer groups deleted except the default group

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I added a new customer and marked all groups as checked and then pressed save just like 
this screen shot

[image]

After that when editing this customer by clicking on Enabled, News or Opt flags from 'The Customers Grid' (GUI) like this screen shot

[image]

When I successfully update the customer then return to the edit page, only the default group is assigned like this screen shot 
[image]

Is that bug or this is the default behavior of Prestashop .. How can I prevent it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I reported a bug on bug tracker here

http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/PSCFV-10880?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

And Thank you rGaillard  and Gregory Roussac for amazing help :)

this is the solution

https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/commit/9611ea1f70ccfa577168d85bf0b854840423ee29

Simply on Customer Class replace updateGroup and addGroups functions by the following:

```
public function updateGroup($list) {
    if ($list && !empty($list)) {
        $this->cleanGroups();
        $this->addGroups($list);
    }
    else
        $this->addGroups(array($this->id_default_group));
}



public function addGroups($groups) {
    foreach ($groups as $group) {
        $row = array('id_customer' => (int) $this->id, 'id_group' => (int) $group);
        Db::getInstance()->insert('customer_group', $row, false, true, Db::INSERT_IGNORE);
    }
}
```